# how to solve React native windows error Unable to find version '2.3.191129002' of package 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml'

Tags: react-native-windows

error running npx react-native run-windows installed visual studio 2019 with required libraries

```
Errors in packages.config projects
    Unable to find version '2.3.191129002' of package 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml'.
      C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.3.191129002' is not found on source 'C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.3.191129002' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.  
    Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub'.
      C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.1.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.1.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git'.
      C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.1.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.1.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.  
    Unable to find version '1.72.0' of package 'boost'.
      C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\: Package 'boost.1.72.0' is not found on source 'C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'boost.1.72.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '3.0.0-preview2.200713.0' of package 'Microsoft.WinUI'.
      C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Microsoft.WinUI.3.0.0-preview2.200713.0' is not found on source 'C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.WinUI.3.0.0-preview2.200713.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.SourceLink.Common'.
      C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Microsoft.SourceLink.Common.1.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Users\BIENV\.nuget\packages\'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.SourceLink.Common.1.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
```

Comment: usin "react-native-windows": "0.63.41"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.